# Change visibility of all listview items(each Listview Item is a linear layout WITH 2 Textviews) and hide the second textview

Tags: android, dynamic, runtime

```
public class MediaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SocialMedia> {

private Context context;
private int resource;
public MediaAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SocialMedia> objects){
    super(context,resource,objects);

    this.resource = resource;
    this.context = context;



}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtVMediaName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtV_Media_Name);
    TextView txtVUserName = convertView.findViewById(txtV_User_Name);
    CheckBox test =  R.id.chk_Display_Info;
    txtVUserName.setVisibility(test.isChecked()?1:0);
    SocialMedia socMedia = getItem(position);


    txtVMediaName.setText(socMedia.getName());
    txtVUserName.setText(socMedia.getUserId());
    return (convertView);

 }
}
```

The Above is my ArrayAdapter, and Below is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CheckBox chkDisInfo;
private ListView lstVSocMedDis;

private class onClickDisplayInfo implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        DetermineDisplay(b);
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chkDisInfo = findViewById(R.id.chk_Display_Info);
    chkDisInfo.setChecked(true);
    lstVSocMedDis = findViewById(R.id.lstv_DisplaySoc);
    loadData();
    chkDisInfo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new onClickDisplayInfo());
}

private void loadData() {
    ArrayList<SocialMedia> calledSocMedia = SocialMedia.getMedia();

    MediaAdapter adapterM = new MediaAdapter(this, R.layout.list_media_info, calledSocMedia);
    lstVSocMedDis.setAdapter(adapterM);
}

private void DetermineDisplay(boolean b) {
}
```

Here is now my SocialMedia Class, which is called 4 times

```
public class SocialMedia {
//Field Variables
private String name;
private String userId;
private int numContacts;

//Constructor 3 PARAM - Name(String) - UserID(String)  - Number of Contact(int)
public SocialMedia(String name, String userId, int numContacts){
    this.name = name;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.numContacts = numContacts;
}

//Setter/Getters

//Getter(String) - Void - Name
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
//Setter(Void) - String - Name
public void setName(String newName){
    this.name = newName;
}

//Getter(String) - Void - UserID
public String getUserId(){
    return this.userId;
}
//Setter(Void) - String - Name
public void setUserId(String newUserId){
    this.userId = newUserId;
}

//Getter(int) - Void - NumContacts
public int getNumContacts(){
    return this.numContacts;
}
//Setter(Void) - int - NumContacts
public void setNumContacts(int newNumContacts){

    this.numContacts = newNumContacts;
}

//Return Type -
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s, %s, %d", this.name,this.userId,this.getNumContacts());
}
public static ArrayList<SocialMedia> getMedia() {

    ArrayList<SocialMedia> socMedia = new ArrayList<>();

    socMedia.add(new SocialMedia("LinkedIn","Batman",100));
    socMedia.add(new SocialMedia("Facebook","Not Bruce Wayne", 100));
    socMedia.add(new SocialMedia("Twitter","Batz_Rulez", 100));
    socMedia.add(new SocialMedia("Instagram","Gotham_Nights", 100));

    return socMedia;
}
```

}

Within `DetermineDisplay` I want to access `txtVUserName` and set the `visibility` to `INVISIBLE` and collapse its size. So that when the user selects the checkbox, all my `listview` items I only display the `SocialMedia` Type. I wish to do this dynamically and access all the values in one call rather than a for loop, but if my thinking is incorrect and a for loop iterating through the `ListView` items and accessing each value is the preferred method. This is just a small feature, but it is required.

Comment: So you want to access all txtVUserName of listview?

Comment: yes, these are within `LinearLayout` and are two `Views` both being `TextView` and the second `Textview` is the required one that needs to be hidden

Comment: Ok try the code i have answered.

Comment: Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public CheckBox chkDisInfo;
private ListView lstVSocMedDis;
MediaAdapter adapterM

private class onClickDisplayInfo implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    DetermineDisplay(b);
}
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
chkDisInfo = findViewById(R.id.chk_Display_Info);
chkDisInfo.setChecked(true);
lstVSocMedDis = findViewById(R.id.lstv_DisplaySoc);
loadData();
chkDisInfo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new onClickDisplayInfo());
}

private void loadData() {
ArrayList<SocialMedia> calledSocMedia = SocialMedia.getMedia();

adapterM = new MediaAdapter(this, R.layout.list_media_info, calledSocMedia);
lstVSocMedDis.setAdapter(adapterM);
}

private void DetermineDisplay(boolean b) {
 adapterM.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Your adapter class code:

```
public class MediaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SocialMedia> {

private Context context;
private int resource;
public MediaAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SocialMedia> objects){
super(context,resource,objects);

this.resource = resource;
this.context = context;



}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
}

TextView txtVMediaName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtV_Media_Name);
TextView txtVUserName = convertView.findViewById(txtV_User_Name);
//CheckBox test =  R.id.chk_Display_Info;

if(((MainActivity)context).chkDisInfo.isChecked()){
    txtVUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
    txtVUserName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
SocialMedia socMedia = getItem(position);


txtVMediaName.setText(socMedia.getName());
txtVUserName.setText(socMedia.getUserId());
return (convertView);

}
}
```

Comment: `setVisibility` only takes `View.INIVISIBLE`,`View.VISIBLE`,`View.GONE` as params. Your solution makes sense, the functionality of this part is difficult